Agora.io BaseStreamProxy::onRtmpStreamingStateChanged(this:0xb400007bfde42180, url: rtmpurl, state: 4, errorCode: 16)
An error occurs when performing rtmp push using agora flutter plugin, BaseStreamProxy::onRtmpStreamingStateChanged(this:0xb400007bfde42180, url: rtmpurl, state: 4, errorCode: 16)
what could be the issue tried to check on agora error codes does not exist.
i contacted agora no helpful response so far since its an automated responce.
